# VBA date format

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have created a VBA function that selects some data from an Access table and puts that data into a temp table. I want to change the format of a date column using the following code so that the date has the leading '0'.

```
Dim lValue As String
lValue = Format(Transaction_Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
Dim i As Integer
SQL = "SELECT ID, PO_Number, Vendor_Company, Incurred_By, Transaction_Type, lValue as Transaction_Date, Investment_ID, " & _
"Notes, Quantity INTO tmp_Tran_Actual FROM Transaction_Data"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

When the code runs, I am prompted to enter the value, in this case the date, for 'lValue'.

I tried adding the `Format(Transaction_Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")` into the select query, but the quotes in the format function would make the whole row seem like it was all text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The db engine is unaware of the VBA variable, so assumes it must be a parameter when it sees the variable name.

Build the variable's *value* into the SQL string and surround it with the `#` delimiter to indicate it's a Date/Time value.

```vb
SQL = "SELECT ID, PO_Number, Vendor_Company, Incurred_By, " & _
    "Transaction_Type, #" & lValue & "# as Transaction_Date, " & _
    "Investment_ID, Notes, Quantity INTO tmp_Tran_Actual FROM Transaction_Data"
```

If you actually wanted `Transaction_Date` as a formatted string, surround the value with single quotes instead of `#`.

```vb
SQL = "SELECT ID, PO_Number, Vendor_Company, Incurred_By, " & _
    "Transaction_Type, '" & lValue & "' as Transaction_Date, " & _
    "Investment_ID, Notes, Quantity INTO tmp_Tran_Actual FROM Transaction_Data"
```

Or maybe this is what you had in mind all along ...

```vb
SQL = "SELECT ID, PO_Number, Vendor_Company, Incurred_By, " & _
    "Transaction_Type, Format(Transaction_Date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as Transaction_Date, " & _
    "Investment_ID, Notes, Quantity INTO tmp_Tran_Actual FROM Transaction_Data"
```

Comment: I ended up using the last suggestion: Format(Transaction_Date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')